# Javascript or jQuery HTML Tooltips for Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, title

Firstly, before someone says it's a duplicate, I'd like to say that none of solutions I have tried so far have worked--and they need to work in IE 11--our unfortunate browser of choice! Note, I have tried using the `tooltip_status_class` class to, somehow, show the tooltips but no success so far.

I have a Bootstrap DataTable being populated in a loop; one of the rows is like:

```
var order_status = '<a href="#" class="tooltip_status_class"><u>' + dyanmicdata + '</u></a>';
```

What I'd like to happen is that, upon hover, an html tooltip shows over the `a href` link when displayed in the table. The content would be the *same* for all rows but have to be HTML, such as:

```
<strong> status 1 </strong>: shipping <br />
<strong> status 2 </strong>: preparing<br />
```

I have jQuery UI and Bootstrap loaded.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share a fiddle or something with the minimal code so that we can update it.

Comment: at fiddle 0t9ht812/1/ but that is showing the tooltip content on page load in IE

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I had a conflict between jQuery and Bootstrap javascript code and also my Tooltip code was embedded three levels inside the file--too much code to share here.

By removing the jQuery UI file from loading and by putting the bootstrap's own Tooltip Javascript code from https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip_html&stacked=h and putting that code after the dynamic code was made, solved the problem.